# How to compile kernel with custom version string?

Tags: kernel, 15.04, compiling, 15.10

I'm trying to compile a stock kernel for ubuntu 15.10 (4.2.0), but would like the kernel version to be different, with minor text addition in the end so it doesn't conflict with the original one.

To be more specific, I'd like the resulting deb packages to be different than the stock ones to be installed and removed without rendering the system useless.
In addition, the displayed string on the boot splash screen should have a custom string as well (which also affects 'uname -r' etc.).

To accomplish the first goal, I followed the article on "Build your own kernel" (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel).
By modifying 'debian.master/changelog' as proposed, the resulting deb packages do get the required change and can be installed while the same kernel version exists.

But it didn't do anything with the boot configuration since the binary kernel image version string remained intact.
So I changed manually the main Makefile to set a custom string in the EXTRA_LOCALVERSION variable. Still no desired effect.

Any ideas or resources to read about proper kernel handling?

Thanks,
Moti.

Comment: I have the same question for Ubuntu 20.04. Followed (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) by modifying 'debian.master/changelog', the result is the same as yours. Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

It's `debian.hwe-xxx/changelog` that should be modified, not `debian.master/changelog`.

### How I found it

It's been many years since the question was asked, but I hope it's still helpful.

Recently I encountered this problem when I tried to rebuild my own version of Ubuntu's 5.8.0-48 kernel. By digging into the `debian/rules` and `debian/rules.d/*` in Ubuntu kernel's source tree, I found that the version string was contained in `abi_release` (check `debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk`). After tracing its definition up:

```
# debian/rules.d/0-common-vars.mk
abi_release := $(release)-$(abinum)

# debian/rules.d/0-common-vars.mk
release := $(shell sed -n '1s/^$(src_pkg_name).*(\(.*\)-.*).*$$/\1/p' $(DEBIAN)/changelog)

# debian/debian.env
DEBIAN=debian.hwe-5.8
```

I tried to change the version string there and it (kind of) worked. The new version would be shown by `uname -a` after booting, but it wouldn't be part of .deb packages' name.